# Non destructive assignation with jq

Tags: json, jq

I got the following data:

```
{
  "things": [
    {
        "name": "lkj",
        "something": [
            "hike"
        ],
        "more_data": "important",
        "other_stuff": "very important"
    },
    {
        "name": "iou",
        "different_more_data": "very important too",
        "more_different_data": [
            "even more"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Each of `things` has an id called "name", with `jq` I can edit it like:

```
jq '(.things[]) |= {name,something:["changed"]}'

{
  "things": [
    {
        "name": "lkj",
        "something": [
            "changed"
        ]
    },
...
```

Unfortunately I lose everything not declared in the right hand of the assignation operation.

Is there a way to make assignations without losing data? So that the result is like this:

```
{
  "things": [
    {
        "name": "lkj",
        "something": [
            "changed"
        ],
        "more_data": "important",
        "other_stuff": "very important"
    },
    {
        "name": "iou",
        "something": [
            "changed"
        ],
        "different_more_data": "very important too",
        "more_different_data": [
            "even more"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply modify your query so that it looks like:

```
 .things[] |= (.something = ["changed"])
```

You can also use `|=` (or one of its siblings, such as `+=`) instead of `=` in the RHS expression, e.g.

```
.things[] |= (.something += ["changed"])
```

If you want to update some, but not all, items, you can still use the above forms. A straightforward approach is to use `if ... then ... else ... end`, for example:

```
 .things[] |= (if .name == "lkj" then .something = ["changed"] else . end)
```

#### Using `select` on the LHS of `|=`

jq (or at least jq since version 1.4) does support the use of `select` on the LHS of `|=`, e.g.

```
(.things[] | select(.name=="lkj")) |= (.something += ["changed"])
```

Answer (score 0):

With `jq`'s **`map`** function:

```
jq '.things |= map(.something = ["changed"])' jsonfile
```

- `map(x)` - apply specified filter `x` for each item of the input array
- `.something = ["changed"]` - set key `something` to an object with array `["changed"]` as a value

The output:

```
{
  "things": [
    {
      "name": "lkj",
      "something": [
        "changed"
      ],
      "more_data": "important",
      "other_stuff": "very important"
    },
    {
      "name": "iou",
      "different_more_data": "very important too",
      "more_different_data": [
        "even more"
      ],
      "something": [
        "changed"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: And to do the change in a few specific names? Like with `select(.name == "lkj" and .name == "iou")`